# Angular JS curly braces stop evaluation at dash in object property name

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm outputting some data into a

tag from an object using AngularJS curly braces {{}}.
It works fine with all object properties like:

```
<p>{{archivi.CARATTERISTICI[0].TESTATA}}</p>
```

but when trying the following:

```
<p> {{archivi.FASE-XD}}</p>
```

It outputs the value of another property in the object named archivi.FASE .  So apparently it stop parsing at the dash '-' and disregards what comes after.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Use bracket notation

```
<p> {{archivi['FASE-XD']}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the js parser interprets dash `-` as a subtract operator.

so just change

```
<p> {{archivi.FASE-XD}}</p>
```

to

```
<p> {{archivi['FASE-XD']}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The '-' is an operator, and will treat it that way. So to access the property, you will need to do {{archivi['FASE-XD']}}